# Manipulating json in powershell from one file to another file - bug or not?

Tags: powershell

Why $jsonObject = $jsonFileData | ConvertFrom-Json
this part

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "css" : ["css/light.css"],
  "js": ["js/content.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
```

is converted to this:

```
"content_scripts":  [
                        {
                            "matches":  "http://*/* https://*/*",
                            "css":  "css/light.css",
                            "js":  "js/content.js",
                            "run_at":  "document_end"
                        }
                    ]
```

as you may notice, there is no square brackets.

Other parts are okay (there is also unnecessary conversions like '<' to '\u003c' but that's another story).

Pasting all code to make it clear:

```
$jsonFileData = Get-Content samplemanifest.json
$jsonObject = $jsonFileData | ConvertFrom-Json
$jsonObject.name='2testani2'
$jsonFileDataToWrite = $jsonObject | ConvertTo-Json
$jsonFileDataToWrite | Out-File sample2.json
```

Maybe someone will shed some light on this?

Comment: Instead of the string array you get from `Get-Content`, try adding `-Raw` and see what happens, i.e., `Get-Content -Raw -Path samplemanifest.json`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1  thanks, I've tried that. looks like does not change anything

Comment: fixed by using -Depth 100